# Adding ASPNETCORE_URL in Dockerfile having no effect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I created a template ASP.Net docker project and made the following changes:

- Change it to Asp.Net 7
- Only `EXPOSE 5000` in the Dockerfile
- Add `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000` to the Dockerfile

Now when I run the Docker locally it tries and fails to go to `https://localhost:0/`. Changing the port in the url to `5000` and changing to `http` doesn't help.

Visual studio is telling me the Container Port is 5000:

[image]

However the ASPNETCORE_URLS remain +443 and +80 in the Environment tab:

[image]

Shouldn't they be swapped out for my rules? I just want to be able to go to `localhost:5000` and see the application. What am I missing?

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["IANSW.Web/IANSW.Web.csproj", "IANSW.Web/"]
RUN dotnet restore "IANSW.Web/IANSW.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/IANSW.Web"
RUN dotnet build "IANSW.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "IANSW.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IANSW.Web.dll"]
```

Comment: Try settings the env in the `final` stage instead of `base`.

Answer (score 2):

Add your `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000;https://+:5001` to the

```
FROM base AS final
```

and also modify `launchSettings.json` "Docker" by adding:

```
"environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://+:5001;http://+:5000"
}
```